Beamer: How to align inside equations without messing up cross-references and the table of contents?
Below is a minimal working example.
The cross-references and table of contents break when I try to use the align environment inside the equation environment. Using array inside equation did not work either.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection]
 \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section One}
\begin{frame}
    Some text. \eqref{eq:some_label}
\end{frame}

\section{Section Two}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{align}
            \dot{x} & = Ax + Bu \\
            y       & = Cx + Du
        \end{align}
        % E = mc^2
        \label{eq:some_label}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The compilation configurations are as follows: latexmk with additional arguments -synctex=1, -interaction=nonstopmode, -file-line-error, -lualatex. The version of latexmk being used is 4.85 and the version of lualatex is 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4).
Update 1
Some of you suggested using aligned instead of align within the equation environment. This modification did help to some extent (thank you!). However, I discovered another peculiar minimal working example (MWE) that is closer to my actual document:
The second section is now changed to
\section{Section Two}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            A &= B \\
            B &= C_\textrm{a}
            % B &= C_{a}
        \end{aligned}
        \right..
        \label{eq:some_label}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}

Note that using \textrm{} makes a difference here.

You cannot use align inside equation.

Unrelated to your question, but if your tex distribution is up-to-date, you should remove the utf8x option.

For separate questions, I would suggest posting a new question and closing this one.

The \textrm{a} should be wrapped in braces since it is a subscript: C_{\textrm{a}}.  This is always true, and if it works without those braces, that's just good luck.

align is a full math display like equation, aligned is just an alignment building block.
Use aligned instead of align if you want a single ref number:
\section{Section Two}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_label}
    \begin{aligned}
        \dot{x} & = Ax + Bu \\
        y       & = Cx + Du
    \end{aligned}
    % E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

or align if you want two seperate ref numbers for each line:
\section{Section Two}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
    \dot{x} & = Ax + Bu \label{eq:some_label}\\
    y       & = Cx + Du
    % E = mc^2
\end{align}
\end{frame}

Regarding update 1: Simply encapsulate ..._\textrm{...} in brackets to ..._{\textrm{...}} to avoid the error.
Regarding the note from @Mico:
Depending on the desired font you have to choose
\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_label}
    \begin{aligned}
        \dot{x} & = Ax + Bu \\
        y       & = C_{\textrm{text}} + Du\\
        y       & = C_{\mathrm{text}} + Du\\
        y       & = C_{\mathsf{text}} + Du\\
    \end{aligned}
    % E = mc^2
\end{equation}



\textrm may not be appropriate. I'd suggest using either \mathrm (if a "Roman" or serif character is what the OP really wants) or \mathsf, given that we're dealing with a beamer document which uses sans-serif text and math fonts by default.

Thank you! I accepted this answer, but could you explain the reason behind this phenomenon? The \textrm{} snippet originally came from another document that did not use beamer and worked fine.

(This answer addresses only the issue raised in the "Update 1" part of the OP's query.)
Incorporating the suggestion given in @binhex's answer, while also adding a new wrinkle to the story, the OP has switched to using
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        A &= B \\
        B &= C_\textrm{a}
        % B &= C_{a}
    \end{aligned}
    \right..
    \label{eq:some_label}
\end{equation}

in one of the slides. The new wrinkle lies in replacing C_{a} with C_\textrm{a}. This generates a LaTeX complaint about a missing } character.
C_\textrm{a} cannot work because it contains a syntax error. The OP should write either C_{\mathrm{a}} or -- much better, since we're dealing with a beamer document that uses sans-serif font faces by default -- C_{\mathsf{a}}.

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts} % optional
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:some_label}
        \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            A &= B \\
            B &= C_{\mathsf{a}}
            % B &= C_{a}
        \end{aligned}\,.
        \right.  
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

